# How to create a follow/followed relationship using Neo4j and Neo4j GraphQL Library with @auth?

Tags: authentication, neo4j, graphql, jwt, neo4j-graphql-js

Using the following schema:

```graphql
type Profile {
      id: ID! @id
      username: String! @unique(constraintName: "unique_email")
      follows: [Profile!]!
        @relationship(
          type: "FOLLOWS"
          properties: "BaseRelationship"
          direction: OUT
        )
      followers: [Profile!]!
        @relationship(
          type: "FOLLOWS"
          properties: "BaseRelationship"
          direction: IN
        )
    }
```

And extending it to use the `@auth` directive:

```graphql
extend type Profile
  @auth(
    rules: [
      { operations: [CREATE, UPDATE, DELETE, UPDATE, CONNECT, DISCONNECT], allow: { username: "$jwt.name" } }
      { operations: [READ], isAuthenticated: true }
    ]
  )
```

I am only getting forbidden when I try the following mutation (jwt.name is `user1`):

```graphql
mutation UpdateProfiles {
  updateProfiles(
    where: { username: "user1" }
    update: {
      follows: [{ connect: [{ where: { node: { username: "user2" } } }] }]
    }
  ) {
    info {
      relationshipsCreated
    }
  }
}
```

Just want to make user1 follow user2 and vice versa. Tried changing `allow` to `bind` and to `where` and variations of the mutation but I can't get it to work.

If I use the same mutation but make both arguments user1, then user1 is able to follow himself, so I assume there is something wrong with not being able to allow the incoming connection to user2.

But how can I allow that the authorized user can follow someone else?